# Should math expressions be evaluated left-to-right?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Suppose I have an expression like this:

$$9\div 7 \times \ 8 - 4 \times 9 + 3 \times 2 \div 4$$

How do I evaluate this expression?

I'm trying to recover my math knowledge. I always check the PEMDAS acronym to see what I evaluate first. But in school I was taught that if two or more operations have equal precedence you solve it left to right.

That seems confusing to me. Can someone clarify what should be done in this case and why?

Comment: It is as you say, but keep in mind even though m preceeds D in PEMDAS, Multiplication and Division are equal precedence so done left-to-right when immediately following each other. Same goes for Addition and Subtraction.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, or I didn't remember. Really.
thanks

Comment: `9 / 7 * 8 - 4 * 9 + 3 * 2 / 4` with no additional context is interpreted as `(((9/7) * 8) - (4*9)) + (3*(2/4))` but a reminder that division signs freefloating like this can be ambiguous.  There can be situations where something like `3/2x` is meant to be interpreted as `3/(2x)` rather than `(3/2)x`.  It is far cleaner to use proper typesetting and write as $\dfrac{3}{2x}$ or as $\dfrac{3}{2}x$ to make it clear what is intended.

Comment: @JMoravitz that's how it's written in school, in blackboards and in schoolbooks too. Never heard about this you're saying. 
Can you please expand on that?

Comment: Given that the standard convention is not left to right, it is unwise to write such an expression on a single line. For that reason I recommend avoiding the division sign $\div$ and always writing something fractional form when there is division. And using parentheses liberally. One should not try write just an unambiguous formula but one that a reader will be able to understand more easily. There are obvious reasons why left-to-right, right-to-left (as in APL), Polish or reverse Polish notation is simpler, but it's not what we use.

Comment: You might like: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/06/science/math-equation-pemdas.html?unlocked_article_code=1.9Uw.1FLY.fnIZ4nlnPCW9&smid=url-share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying and division are "stronger" than adding and subtracting,so you do them first.But when you have only multiplying and divison they are equal.If you keep the first number in place,you can change the order of the other operations,for example:

$1000 \times 6 \div 5 \times 7 \div 2$ is the same as $1000 \times 7 \div 2 \div 5 \times 6$ or $1000 \div 2 \times 6 \times 7 \div 5$.

Also adding and subtracting are equal.When evaluating you usually go from left to right,but first do the multiplying and division,then return back to the left side and start again, this time adding and subtracting.There are other operations that are even "stronger",but what comes in brackets must always be done first!

In your example you go like this:

$$9 \div 7 \times 8 - 4 \times 9 + 3 \times 2 \div 4=(9 \div 7 \times 8)-(4 \times 9) + (3 \times 2 \div 4)$$

There are many other rules  and shortcuts that help us calculate faster,but you should first get used to the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.I would have used the simbol ÷ but I can get only / or : on my keyboard.